# Is there an inbuilt jquery method to open a pop up within a page?

Tags: jquery, popup

Instead of opening a new pop up I want to show a "pseudo pop up" where I am graying out rest of the page and just showing the div, giving the user an impression that its a popup.

There are many examples out there on how to do this. I was wondering if the jquery library itself had something that I could use (as opposed to downloading other third party javascript libraries).

Comment: I don't understand. your link is atually a tutorial+demo of what you need. why don't you use it?

Comment: Are you talking about modal ?

Comment: Removed that link. I hope my question is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing in jQuery core that will do all the work for you, although there are hundreds of plugins.

The core idea is just to absolutely position a `div` in the middle of the page.

Perhaps with another one in between (z-index-wise) it and the page, with the middle one having some middle opacity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about modal, there are plenty of them like:   http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox

Answer (score 0):

It's not a popup. It's a modal dialog emulation. You can use ColorBox for this: http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox